# How to stop music playing after last song in `Listview`

Tags: c#, uwp

In my UWP app for Raspberry pi3 I have a music player that plays songs from a `ListView`. You can select any song in the `ListView` and then it will automatically play the next song. The problem I am facing is that when it reaches the last song and finishes it plays it again and doesn't stop. Like it goes in a loop on the last song instead of stopping after playing it.

Can someone direct me on how to stop the loop?

This is my code:

```
    private async void SongClicked(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(e.ClickedItem.ToString());
        if (file != null)
        {
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            mediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
            mediaElement.Play();
        }
    }

    private void mediaItemList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void objMediaPlayer_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement.Play();
    }

    private async void objMediaPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex <= AudioFilesLV.Items.Count)
        {
            AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex = AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex = 1;
            var file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(AudioFilesLV.SelectedItem.ToString());
            if (file != null)
            {
                var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                mediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
                mediaElement.Play();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mediaElement.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In the selectedIndex if statement try with < instead of <=.

Comment: Hi Thanks,  I have tried that but not working, still plays the last in repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow,
could it possible that the problem is in the first line of the if condition from the event *objMediaPlayer_MediaEnded*. Because you reach the end of the list and set

```
AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex = AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

The *SelectedIndex* should now again smaller then *AudioFilesLV.Items.Count*.

The line should change to:

```
AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex = AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex + 1;
```

Bcause then the you count up the the *SelectedIndex* in the if case. At the moment the *SelectedIndex* should always be 1.

Her are an example if you need to count up the *SelectedIndex* to select the next song:

```
private async void objMediaPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // If the end of the ListView is reached and the last song was played stop.
    if ((AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex + 1) == AudioFilesLV.Items.Count)
    {
       mediaElement.Stop();
    }
    else
    {
       // This line you should try to change. When the last song was not played 
       //-> select next one and play them.
        AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex = AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex + 1;
        var file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(AudioFilesLV.SelectedItem.ToString());
        if (file != null)
        {
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            mediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
            mediaElement.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Then for you information why I have done:

```
(AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex + 1)
```

in the example. Because *AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex* (SelectedIndex start at 0) is one less then *AudioFilesLV.Items.Count* (Count starts at 1) in every case.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, not quite following what you saying.  Could you possibly give an example as per my code above?

Comment: Hello, I hope the example is ok so and helps you to fix your problem.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you this is working now and thank you for the explanation as well!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private async void objMediaPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex += 1;
        if (AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex <= AudioFilesLV.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            var file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(AudioFilesLV.SelectedItem.ToString());
            if (file != null)
            {
                var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                mediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
                mediaElement.Play();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mediaElement.Stop();
        }
    }
```